# pylint reports unable to import error when the module can be imported

Tags: pylint

I have a wagtail app and the settings directory in in *bfg_web*

A simplified tree of my system is:

```
├── bfg
│   ├── bfg_components
│   │   └── bfg_components
│   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │       └── source
│   │           └── bfg_common.py
│   └── bfg_wag
│       ├── bfg_web
│       │   ├── __init__.py
│       │   └── settings
│       └── duo
│           ├── engine.py
│           └── __init__.py
└── phoenix-link.txt
```

In **engine.py** I have the code

```
from bfg_components import bfg_common
```

**bfg_web/_*init.py_***

```
sys.path.append('../bfg_components')
```

pylint is reporting

> Unable to import 'bfg_components'pylint(import-error)

but the module is imported and functions correctly

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This should help: `from bfg.bfg_components.bfg_components.source import bfg_common`

But if it will not help, to be clear:

1. What version of `pylint` do you use and what version of `python`?
2. What `pylint` command do you execute with what parameters?

I tried the same structure as yours on python 3.7.9 and pylint 2.6.0

```
├── bfg
│   ├── bfg_components
│   │   └── bfg_components
│   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │       └── source
│   │           └── bfg_common.py
│   └── bfg_wag
│       ├── bfg_web
│       │   ├── __init__.py
│       │   └── settings
│       └── duo
│           ├── engine.py
│           └── __init__.py
└── phoenix-link.txt
```

And didn't get your error

> Unable to import 'bfg_components'pylint(import-error)

But got another:

```
|no-name-in-module          |1           |
+---------------------------+------------+
|missing-function-docstring |1           |
+---------------------------+------------+
|invalid-name               |1           |
```